# Linux (Vi preferably) Delete overlapping coordinates but first without manually approving each deletion

Tags: linux, vi

I am dealing with a pdb file, which basically contains many atoms and their coordinates. The first and second lines looks like this:

ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 Z   1       6.703   3.973  -2.488  1.00  0.00      ZINC

ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 Z   1      -2.639   3.973  -2.488  1.00  0.00      ZINC

I have overlapping atoms. This means, the three numbers (in the example 6.703   3.973  -2.488 in line 1, and -2.639   3.973  -2.488 in line 2) appear many times throughout the file. Each line, however, has a different atom number (in the example, the 1 and the 2 after ATOM). Thus, the lines for the overlapping atoms aren't exactly the same. The coordinates are. I want to delete all the lines with the repeated coordinates but one. I do not care about the order. So far, I have manually search for each set of coordinates and replaced them but the first appearance with a three @ characters, to later delete all lines containing @@@. For example, for line 1 I am doing this:

```
:%s/6.703   3.973  -2.488/@@@/gc
:g/@@@/d
```

This file, however, is extremely long. I am afraid doing this for every line will take me days, and there is a big change that I will make mistakes. Is there an easier way for this? I prefer using the vi editor, but emacs works too.

Thank you!!!

Comment: [vi.se] is the best place to ask Vi questions, and [emacs.se] is for Emacs questions.

Answer (score 2):

With the format you show in the question (whitespace-delimited fields), you can use a common awk idiom to remove "duplicates" directly from the command-line:

```
awk '!/^ATOM / || !dupes[$7,$8,$9]++' infile >outfile
```

This prints any line that does **not** start `ATOM`  and the first atom line for any given set of coordinates.

The idiom `!f[x]++` works as:

- the first time array element `f[x]` is accessed, for any particular value of `x`, it is assigned empty string
- `!` means "not". `!`(empty string) equates to true
- `++` increments a value by one (initially to 1, then 2, 3, 4, etc) - empty string is treated as zero. (`++x` increments before `x` is used; `x++` increments after)
- `!`(positive number) is false

---

Depending on the layout of the file, you may be able to run a visual check by something like:

```
diff -u infile outfile | sort -k7,9 | less
```

This should display the atom lines grouped by coordinate.

You can use `-S` in less to disable wrapping (then left/right arrow to scroll sideways).

The first line of each group will start with space, the rest with hyphen.

Then searching for `^ .*` in less provides simple highlighting.

Any non-atom lines should be prefixed with space. Something went wrong if there are any prefixed with plus or hyphen.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! I am dealing with this again. Your suggestion seems to delete all the replicas, including the first time the coordinates appear in the file. I would like to keep one atom that contains these coordinates, and delete exclusively the duplicates. Is there something that could be done for this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is impossible for my code to delete **all** replicas. Are you using exactly the awk code I provided?